# Getting better results with OCR

Tags: image, text, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract to get text from tiff files, I already process the image with textcleaner and localtresh from imagemagick, how would I go about further improving accuracy?

Everything has to done automatically from a terminal, I can't hard core any file names or anything because I will be uploading a file into a form and processing it.

Now after all the processing I get these results:

[image]

[image]

Which after being read by tesseract are not very accurate.
I have traineddata for the language I am using and custom tessaract params which help a little but not that much

terminal commands used:

```
convert -verbose -density 400 -trim {$convertpdf} -quality 100 -flatten -sharpen 0x1.0 {$tiff}
/www/textcleaner -l p -g -e normalize -f 42 -o 15 -u -s 1 -T -p 5
/www/localthresh -m 1 -r 25 -b 5 -n yes
```

Comment: Increase the density to 800 or 1200. Your point size may be still too small

Comment: that did not help at all, is there a way to automatically correct the image my removing the borders from tables and cropping the unwanted stuff around?